# POST 400 Bad Request even though there is data there (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: ajax, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to POST data via an AJAX request using Django Rest Framework but I keep getting this error:

```
POST /api/uservenue/ HTTP/1.1" 400 37
{"venue":["This field is required."]}
```

[I am posting data for that field](https://ibb.co/PDHMkmZ), however, and cannot work out what I am doing wrong.

AJAX Call:

```
const addVenueToList = function(listId, venueName) {
  console.log(venueName);
  console.log(listId);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/api/uservenue/',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').value,
      'venue': JSON.stringify(venueName),
      'list': parseInt(listId)
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('User added: ' + data)
    },
  });
}
```

Here is my serializer:

```
class UserVenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    venue = mapCafesSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserVenue
        fields = ['id', 'list', 'venue']
```

Here is the relevant model:

```
class UserVenue(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(mapCafes, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    list = models.ForeignKey(UserList, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['list','venue']

[...]

class mapCafes(models.Model): 
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    cafe_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_long = models.FloatField()
    cafe_lat = models.FloatField()
    geolocation = models.PointField(geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
    venue_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'a_cafes'
```

Comment: Just wanted to understand the flow here, so as user I am suppose to send one venue to backend? Or venue is array (list) of venues?

Comment: Just the venue. So the user clicks on a venue they want to add to a list, it is then added to the list and can be referenced later along with the address etc. (the venue already exists in the database, the user is just storing it in one of their lists) I feel like the problem may lie in the ``UserVenue`` model.

Comment: I think it does. Let me provide you with answer

Comment: @VJMagar that would be fantastic thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class UserVenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    venue = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserVenue
        fields = ['id', 'list', 'venue']

    def create(self, validated_data):
       """Overrides the create method to create the UserVenue instance"""

        validated_data["venue"] = mapCafes.objects.get(cafe_name=validated_data.get("venue")
        return UserVenue.objects.create(**validated_data)
```